# Why can't I mark in a map with a list of values using folium.Map() function?

Tags: python, list, pycharm, folium

I'm working with folium packages in Python3.x (IDE PyCharm) and when I want to indicate the location of a marker point in the map using the `folium.Map()` function, in `location=[,]`, I use a list that contains the different values of latitude and longitude. Something like this:

```
i = 0
while i <= countEquipments: #number of equipments
    folium.Marker(location=[mylist[i]["lat"], mylist[i]["lon"]], popup=mylist[i]["name"], tooltip="Click").add_to(map)
    i = i+1
```

But it gives me an error. Someone knows how to solve it?

Comment: What error are you getting? What is `mylist` and how does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

'map' is function name in python. I would name my map something else (mymap)
I loaded the list in pandas, and iterated through it using iterrows.

```
import folium
import pandas as pd

#create an empty map
mymap = folium.Map(location=[37, -102], zoom_start=5)
#load the list into a pandas dataframe
mylistdf= pd.DataFrame(mylist)
for currentpoint in mylistdf.iterrows(): 
    folium.Marker(location=[currentpoint[1]["Lat"], currentpoint[1]["Lon"]], popup=currentpoint[1]["name"], tooltip="Click").add_to(mymap)
```